# How do you pad the history number in the PS1 prompt with 0's?

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash prompt that starts with the history number padded with zeros, so that it is always at least three characters long:

```
001 user@hostname:~ $
```

I tried padding the special `PS1` symbol `\!` with `printf`:

```sh
function padded_history {
    printf "%03d" "\!"
}
PS1="$(padded_history) \u@\h:\w \$"
```

But I get the following error:

```
-bash: printf: \!: invalid number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape sequence `\!` must be embedded in the value that is assigned to `PS1`. And you need to use single quotes around the value to prevent premature expansions.

```
PS1='$(printf "%03d" "\!") \u@\h:\w \$ '
```